# DataTables search box also clicking sort button

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have this data tables code where I modified it to have the search input moved from the footer of the table to the header of the table. One side affect from this is the table also lets you sort the column on the top next to the search input box. One side affect now that I cant figure out how to solve is how can i make it so when i click in the text input box it also does not sort each and every time i click in the search input box. Ideally these should be independent events and the sort functionality should not be happening when I click in the input box.

I have also put together this jsFiddle showing my issue [JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/mastarke/xtm1qvy7/14/)

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#gitHubTable th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

    // DataTable
    var table = $('#gitHubTable').DataTable({

        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel',
        ],

        initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;

                $( 'input', this.header() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }
    });

} );
```

Comment: See [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering) from the official DataTables site. It works around your problem by separating filter inputs from sortable headings. It first clones the header row, to facilitate this: `$('#example thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#example thead' );`

Comment: The example also uses "FixedHeader", which is not directly relevant to what you are asking about - you can ignore that part.

Comment: Thank you did not see this in the documentation. This is what I was looking for.